# how to deal with visifire chart when a number of datapoints to display

Tags: wpf, charts, visifire

In my application, I met a problem about visifire chart. I used the code like that:

```
var series = new DataSeries { RenderAs = RenderAs.Spline, LegendText = legendText};

source.Select(p => new DataPoint
{
   AxisXLabel = p.DateTime.ToString("yy-MM-dd\n  HH:mm"), YValue = p.Value ?? 0,
}).ToList().ForEach(p => series.DataPoints.Add(p));
_chart.Series.Add(series);
```

When there are a number of datapoints, the app's performance is very serious. Is there a good idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you please tell me which version of Visifire are you using and how many datapoints you are working with?

Comment: I am using vision is 4.0 and work with more than 1000 datapoints

Comment: Please use the latest version of Visifire and check.You can download it from http://www.visifire.com/download_silverlight_wpf_controls.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There has been major performance improvements in Visifire 5.0. So I suggest you to use Visifire 5.0 and set [LightWeight](http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Reference/Attribute_Reference/LightWeight.htm) property to True in DataSeries and also use [LightDataPoint](http://www.visifire.com/documentation/Visifire_Documentation/Charts/Reference/Chart_Elements_Reference/LightDataPoint.htm) instead of normal DataPoint.